# Quartz_Spring_Tomcat examples

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, tomcat7

This what i've:

Quartz 2.1.3

Spring 3.1.1

Tomcat 7.0

I've a non web app which is running fine with quartz (with crontrigger) and spring. Now i need web-enable (simple JSP based app) this application. I've searched the net but could find examples.

Could anybody point me to a simple HOWTO/webpage? I dont want to make any changes to the existing spring+quartz app but just need to have some web layer on top of this.

TIA

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What does this app do that you want to Web'ify. Any app can be turned in webapp with adding a servler\jsp layer above desktop app. What is the problem you are facting

Comment: I've two classes (A and B) and beans.xml file.

class A has the main method which has a single stmt: new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")

class B implements QuartzJobBean and provides implementation for executeInteral method

the crontrigger info is configured in the beans.xml

Now I want to simply make a WAR file with a dummy JSP/servlet and let the existing B class do its job (class A of course need not be there).

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

ive used [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) before to get a decent boilerplate app running. Back in the day they allowed you to customize the frameworks used in your sample app. Im sure you can still do this.